# special type of notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, ime

i need special type of notification, not the normal one, i need this feature:

1) notification appear one the right side of statusbar (notification bar)
2) it haven't any pending intent, so when you pull down statusbar nothing relevant to that notification exists.

in simple word it's just a text or icon appear just in right side of notification bar like the below picture.

in the picture, the notification created by the default HTC IME (for HTC CHACHA)

i'm writing a new IME so i need something like this.

i tried the default notification and played with it's option, but it didn't give me this result.

witch option of  notification or notificationManager class can i use to do this? or may be you know new method?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The icons on the right-hand side of the status bar are reserved for the system. You can't place anything there, sorry.

Comment: but the default IME is an app, how this app can do this?

Comment: That appears to be a [special HTC thing](https://eclub.htc.com/us/support/howto.aspx?p_id=563&id=317462&p_name=htc-status-att).